# Mean free path for charged molecule inside air

Tags: charge, air, molecules, mean-free-path

## Question

I would like to compute the mean free path ($\lambda$) for a "heavy" charged molecule ($M$amu, $q$ charge) in a low pressure gaz (air, but also ions such as Ca$^+$). I think I figured out how to do this for neutral particles, but I don't know how to extend this to charged particle. I'm looking for such charged particle model.

## My first approach

I tried to derive the solution from the mean free path of one molecule (diameter $d$) inside a pure gas made of itself. It's a three step process. I first consider one mocospecies gas, then add one big molecule, then consider a polyspecies gas.

### 1. Only one monospecies gas

Suppose we have a monospecies gas (with pressure $P$, temperature $T$). Let us calculate the mean free path for one molecule of this gas :
$$
\lambda = \frac{R T}{\sqrt{2}\pi d P}
$$
with $d$ the molecular diameter.
From this we can have the mean time between collisions $\bar{t}$ = $\lambda$/$\bar{v}$, with $\bar{v}$ calculated with Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution.

### 2. Introducing one different molecule

Then consider we are still inside a monospecies gas, but we want to compute the mean free path of the "heavy" molecule $M$. I have now the same formula but the definition for d is different :

$d$ is both diameters summed (one gas molecule + one "heavy" molecule).

### 3. Considering a gas made of two species (air typically)

Now the "heavy" molecule will meet two different species during its journey through the gas. I calculate MFP for each gas alone, then compute $\lambda$.

We have one "heavy" molecule (diameter $d$).

We have two gases ($d_1$ and $d_2$ molecular diameters, $P_1$ and $P_2$ partial pressures)

$$
\lambda_1 = \frac{R T}{\sqrt{2}\pi (d+d_1) P_1}\\
\lambda_2 = \frac{R T}{\sqrt{2}\pi (d+d_2) P_2}
$$

I propose the final MFP $\lambda$ should be a mean value, with coefficients being proportionnal to the collision probability. This probability I don't know how to compute but I suppose I can use the collision frequency, aka $\bar{t_i^{-1}} = \bar{v} / \lambda  $. Then I have the formula I propose as MFP :
$$
\lambda = \frac{\bar{t_1^{-1}}\lambda_1 + \bar{t_2^{-1}}\lambda_2}{\bar{t_1^{-1}}+\bar{t_2^{-1}}}
$$

What do you think of this approach ? Considering charge approximation is it okay ? Then should I consider any charge effect on the "molecular diameter". Should I replace d by some sort of cross-section ? Or start with a totally different approach ?

## Supplementary informations

I work with a quite huge range of pressures : from 1atm to $10^-9$ mbar. Usually there's no problem for such low pressures because MFP is something like km, but in my experiment I am working with "big" molecules (1Mamu), with "many" charges (10, 20 ...), so I suppose I may need to calculate MFP for lower pressures than expected.